# blender bump map tearing

Tags: uv

Merhaba! blender programında bir tekerlek modeli üzerinde çalışırken bump map haritalamasının yanlış olduğunu farkettim. daha doğrusu 2 boyutlu haritalamada sıkıntı yoktu ama 3 boyutlu modelde yırtılma oluyor. ve tekerleğe belli bir açıdan bakıldığında bu yırtılma çok kötü duruyor. işte görsel:

---

Hello there! While working on a wheel model in the blender program, I noticed that the bump map mapping was wrong. More precisely, there was no problem in 2-dimensional mapping, but tearing occurs in the 3-dimensional model. and this tearing looks very bad when the wheel is viewed from a certain angle. here is the visual:
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This can sometimes happen when having the normal map set to sRGB. Make sure it's set to non-color.

Comment: thanks but how can I make this image non-color?

Comment: Hey :). It's in the image texture node - ColorSpace: Non-Color.

Comment: thanks Jachym Michal. I will try.